# What is the aspnet_client folder for under the IIS structure?

Tags: iis

I notice that there's frequently an aspnet_client folder under the standard IIS web folder structure. What is this used for? Is it needed?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In the .NET 1.1 days and before, this folder provided ASP.NET with its JavaScript support for the validation controls and other functionality.  If you don't have a .NET 1.1 site  or older running it should be safe to delete it.  I would rename it first to ensure it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: It shows up to remind you how not to do things like that anymore... :)

Comment: Even if you are now out of the .Net 1.1 days you can use Crystal Reports, that unfortunately still use mentioned folder (and probably there is also other software with same behavior). So, at least, make backup before deleting the folder

Answer (score 68):

In addition to what others have said, it's usually created by the aspnet_regiis tool, which can be (re-)run by things like Windows Update/AddRemove Windows components/IIS.  So sometimes even if you do delete it, it can come back randomly. There may be a way to stop this behavior, but I haven't found it (maybe changing the application version to .NET 2 would do it actually).

So unless you're using certain features of .NET 1.0/1.1 (validation, Smart Navigation etc) you can delete it without any problems, just don't be too surprised if it comes back!

Comment: I find it comes back periodically. What's most frustrating about it is that everytime it does come back, it breaks WebDeploy as the account under which that runs does not have access to delete the aspnet_client folder created!

Comment: @RussCam I exactly has the same problem. It breaks the WebDeploy for the same reason. Did anybody find a way to stop this folder to be created randomly?

Comment: I just innocently installed DotNet Framework 4.5 and a short time later our WebDeploy deployment (triggered via TeamCity) broke for the SAME reason.  The darn folder came back again as a result of installing 4.5.  Somebody, please make it stop.

Comment: I have now resorted to actually adding these folders to our deployment package so TeamCity doesn't try to remove them.  It feels like it's polluting our code base, but hopefully will stop the power struggle between ASP.NET and our app deployment.

Comment: I am also serious annoyed by this folder coming back all the time, we have no asp.net 1.x sites, and yet seemingly every automatic windows update puts this bloody folder in every site so breaking all my web deploys. I agree with @Michael12345 that its not a great solution to add useless folders to SC just to make deploys continue to work and not need manually fixing every Monday after the weekend's win updates add it back to each and every site (with incorrect ACL perms). Annoying !

Comment: The folder seems to appear after windows updates has been installed, so on our web servers I've added a scheduled task which runs `aspnet_regiis.exe -ea` when WindowsUpdateClient logs EventID 19. Hopefully this will be a good workaround until someone finds a permanent fix.

Answer (score 16):

aspnet_client is a folder for "resources which must be served via HTTP, but are installed on a per-server basis, rather than a per-application basis".

Some of the uses of aspnet_client include storing resources (eg. JavaScript, images) for:

- JavaScript for ASP.NET Web Forms controls when using client-side validation (mainly to manhandle older browsers like IE5, it seems)
- ASP.NET 2.0 (until at framework 4.0) for 'Global Themes' (global to all sites on a server, that is)
- some versions of Crystal Reports

There probably are/will-be further (ab)uses of this folder in the future.  Needless to say, since it contains things which are "necessary for the application to run correctly" but which "are not supposed to be deployed by the application", it will remain something of a nightmare for both developers and system administrators.

It seems that the 'prototype' for the contents of the folder is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot, and it seems reasonable to suppose that if any given IIS website lacks a /aspnet_client resource, then IIS will try to do the right thing and ... as a last resort ... make a physical folder in the web site root folder, and copy the files there.  It seems that IIS will do this at least when "ASPNET_regiis /c" is invoked a given server - which probably occurs automatically at some critical junctures ... like when .NET framework updates are applied to a server which has the IIS role.

Strategies for handling the aspnet_client directory include:

- specifying a virtual directory mapped to C:\inetpub\wwwroot in the hope that IIS will forgo creating a physical directory
- deleting the physical directory from time to time if you're sure your site doesn't need it and it really bothers you
- ignoring aspnet_client
- running "ASPNET_regiis /c" yourself if you're missing the folder, and need it

Probably most importantly, as a developer, you should clearly understand and document your applications' dependencies on the aspnet_client directory, and make sure that your installation procedure has relevant instructions for making sure that the directory exists.  However, you should probably not bother to actually *supply* the directory as part of your packaged web application or web site - how could you possibly do this for each version of the .NET framework which the server will see over the lifetime of your application?!

Some links I will come back to later:

- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/certification/mcts/9780735657489/2dot-using-master-pages-themes-and-caching/ch02s03_html?query=((aspnet_client))&reader=html&imagepage=#snippet
- [What is the aspnet_client folder in my ASP.NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947047/what-is-the-aspnet-client-folder-in-my-asp-net-website)
- [iis express path for global theme directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444720/iis-express-path-for-global-theme-directory)
  http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/microsoft-aspdotnet/0735621772/aspdotnet-configuration/111?query=((aspnet_client))#X2ludGVybmFsX0J2ZGVwRmxhc2hSZWFkZXI/eG1saWQ9MDczNTYyMTc3Mi8xMTE=
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/microsoft-aspdotnet/9780471785989/working-with-themes/ch41lev1sec8?query=((aspnet_client))&reader=html&imagepage=#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODA0NzE3ODU5ODklMkZjaDQxbGV2MnNlYzEwJnF1ZXJ5PSgoYXNwbmV0X2NsaWVudCkp
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/microsoft-aspdotnet/067232542x/performing-form-validation-with-validation-controls/ch03lev1sec1?query=((aspnet_client))&reader=html&imagepage=#snippet
- http://scn.sap.com/thread/3157366

Comment: so if you add aspnet_client folder under wwwroot its contents will be copied to each web app you install I guess

Answer (score 8):

It also has certain icons and scripts that are required for crystal reports to run properly even in versions later than 1.1

Comment: Yah, found this out the hard way.  I moved our Ripplestone instance from a virtual directory under the Default Web Site to it's own website, and everything started breaking weird in Ripplestone.  I looked at the javascript console, and saw that it was looking for stuff under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13`

Not sure if it was the _right_ thing to do or not, but I just copied the whole aspnet_client folder from the root to the directory my Ripplestone instance lived in.

Answer (score 3):

The folder is usually for storing client side Javascript, which ASP.NET uses for things like validation.

It should be safe to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd add this here as this is the link I kept being directed to when I googled this question. Apparently with .NET 4.0 and newer this folder is no longer needed and can be removed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Installshield to configure ASP.net website, be aware that this feature was present in Installshield 2010 and is missing in Installshield 2012.
[image: Installshield 2010 Vs 2012]

Comment: Some features are not present in IS2010. Try more previous versions.