# special aspnet_client folder for ASP .Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I read that aspnet_client folder contain script which is used by asp .net website for Navigation and validation. This is created by visual studio i guess. When i created two different website, Visual Studio 2008 has already created aspnet_client folder for one of them and it has not created for another website.

I would like to know when Visual Studio 2008 will create this folder and why? is there any reason why it does not create this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two duplicates of this question on StackOverflow. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210440/what-is-the-aspnetclient-folder-for-under-the-iis-structure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947047/what-is-the-aspnetclient-folder-in-my-asp-net-website) for more information.

Comment: Interestingly, when you add a question with this title, neither of those questions appear in the "What's related" section, but a simple search for "aspnet_client" reveals them quickly.

Comment: Yes. That is why i added this questions and the already answered questions never came up.