# iis express path for global theme directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, ASP.NET Webforms, Framework .NET 3.5 and **IIS Express** (also called WebMatrix).

I get the following compilation error in Visual Studio with my WebSite :

`Theme 'MySweetyTheme' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.`

**Do you know where the global theme directories is located with IIS Express ?**

(My favorite search engine seems unfriendly this time).

For information :

- With IIS 5.0/6.0 the global theme path is : `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\Themes`
- With Cassini (ASP.NET Development Server) the global theme path is : `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\Themes`

Comment: I opened a topic on IIS forum but I'm still looking for an answer : http://forums.iis.net/p/1176796/1976366.aspx#1976366

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the IIS [forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1176796.aspx). The answer is included below.

> IIS Express will search themes located
>   in
>   [SiteRootPath]\aspnet_client\system_web\[version]\Themes
>   directory, the SiteRootPath is
>   physical path of the root application,
>   version is .NetFramwork version. Sub
>   applications will be able to share
>   themes in that directory.

Comment: Yes, I created the topic on IIS forum but the answer is incomplete. I added a virtual directory in "applicationhost.config" (<virtualDirectory path="/aspnet_client" physicalPath="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client" />) but I can't create a virtual directory available for all WebSites in IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your theme files under the *framework* folder.

For example:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles\Themes\MyTheme
```